# Weblogic redeployment fails due to weblogic.deploy.api.tools.deployer.DeployerException

Tags: maven, deployment, weblogic, war, weblogic11g

When I try to redeploy war file to Weblogic 10.3.6, I am getting the following error

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.oracle.weblogic:weblogic-maven-plugin:10.3.6.0:redeploy
  (default-cli) on project myapp: weblogic.deploy.api.tools.deployer.DeployerException: 
  Task 16 failed: [Deployer:149026]deploy application myapp on mymgdserver.`

I can successfully deploy and undeploy applications though.

What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

The error goes away after deleting the weblogic’s cache located under Admin server or managed server